# Get repeated data from database when mousemove using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have data which I got from database and It's in display.php.

Then mousemove is used to display data. But the data keeps repeating when I do mouseover. This is the code to mouse move

```
$(line.node).mousemove(get_over_handler(country));
```

and this is some code in function `get_over_handler(country)`

```
function get_over_handler(country) {
    return function (event) {
        color_country(country, selected_color);
        var country_name = $("#country_name_popup");
        country_name.empty();
        country_name.append("<span id='popup_country_name'> " + code_to_name[country] + "</span><table width='100%' style='border-spacing:20px;'>");
        var id_dataset = $("#dataset_select").find('option:selected').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "display.php",
            data: {ibukota: country, id_dataset: id_dataset},
            success: function (data) {
                country_name.append(data);
            }
        });
```

My question is how to prevent repeated data I got from database?

Comment: EDIT: what happens when you hover out of the element?
EDIT2: I think querying for every mouse move is inefficient. it would kill your server.
EDIT3: I think you have an extra `append` in you `success` or the `append` before the `success`

Comment: Edit : when I hover out the element sometimes it return data from database correctly but sometimes It return the data twice (duplicate)

Comment: @JohnPangilinan How to prevent querying for every mouse move? I have no idea

Comment: your request are async, they are concurrent and sometimes, the empty() of other request are fired before the success of other requests. Try to add this lines `var country_name = $("#country_name_popup");
        country_name.empty();
        country_name.append("<span id='popup_country_name'> " + code_to_name[country] + "</span><table width='100%' style='border-spacing:20px;'>");` inside your `success: function(){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your function to:

```
function get_over_handler(country) {
    return function (event) {
        color_country(country, selected_color);
        var id_dataset = $("#dataset_select").find('option:selected').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "display.php",
            data: {ibukota: country, id_dataset: id_dataset},
            success: function (data) {
                var country_name = $("#country_name_popup");
                country_name.empty();
                country_name.append("<span id='popup_country_name'> " + code_to_name[country] + "</span><table width='100%' style='border-spacing:20px;'>");
                country_name.append(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```